# The set of all bounded functions on $X$ is a Banach space with respect to the uniform norm.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, normed-spaces, banach-spaces

> Let $X$ be a nonempty set.
> Define $B(X)$ be the set of all bounded functions on $X$. Then $B(X)$ is a Banach space with respect to $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$, the uniform norm on $B(X)$.

After I know that $f_n \to f$ in $B(X)$ with respect to $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ $\iff$ $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $X$, and $\{f_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $B(X)$ with respect to $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ $\iff$ $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly on $X$.
I want to prove this statement.

Given an Cauchy sequence $\{f_n\}$ in $B(X)$ with respect to $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$, then $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly on $X$, say to $f$. Since $f$ is bounded on $X$ (by uniform convergence and $\{f_n\}$ is in $B(X)$) and $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $X$, $f_n \to f$ in $B(X)$ with respect to $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$.

Comment: You did not specify the ranges of your functions. If the functions are real or complex functions you have to use the  completness of $\mathbb R$/ $\mathbb  C$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy $f$ is a real-valued function. I know the proof using completeness of $\Bbb R$, but why I can not prove by this way? Is the two fact I have mentioned can not apply in this situation?

Comment: You just said that any Cauchy sequence in $B(X)$ converges uniformly. That is what you are asked to prove.

Comment: Your proof might be ok, but you should spell it out.